# How to install SL4A on emulated android phone

Tags: android, python, sl4a

i'm currently reading through head first python and upon reaching chapter 8 I got stuck.  The book wants me to download SL4A from the link http://code.google.com/p.android-scripting however that link no longer works.  So I did some searching and found the file on github.  My real problem is when I try to download it on the emulated device it just says waiting for data connection and it never downloads.  I am wondering if there is a way to fix this.  Any help is appreciated thanks!

EDIT: to get it to work I downloaded both files from here https://github.com/kuri65536/python-for-android/blob/master/README.md
then I copied the files to the folder

**C:\Users\lucas\android-sdks\platform-tools**

then I opened CMD and cd to the path above.

then use the command:

**adb install (filepath)**

for both files and they appeared on the emulated device.

Answer (score 0):

Download to your pc and push through ADB.

Comment: i used the command adb push SL4A(folder the file is in)  /sdcard but how do I locate it on the emulated device?

Comment: You can use adb shell to look at emulator from console. 
From os you have to use file explorer.

Comment: thank you it worked I got both of the files installed except I am missing the python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Download files and adb install worked for me in my installation (Windows 10, android studio 2.1.1) with minor differences:

1) adb command is located in:
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\Mysdk\platform-tools
Need to add to path

2) Needed release sl4a-r6.1.1-x86-debug.apk. Downloaded it from [release pages](https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/releases)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also reading through HeadFirstPython and got stuck at this stage (with the error: `app not installed`). I tried the abs method above and ended up with yet another problem: `install_failed_no_matching_abis.` After a lot of research, I got to understand that the "native libraries" of the sl4a.apk were not matching the system architecture of my emulated android. In other words, if one wants a faster emulator in android studio, he ought to use an x86 architecture android; but the problem with that is scripting layer for android is programmed to work on ARM architectures hence the 'install_failed_no_matching_abis' error.

The solution that worked for me was to go back to AVD in Android Studio, delete the downloaded emulator (which was of x80 cpu/abi) and download one with armeabiv7 cpu, recommended level=24. It took a lot of trial and error to get to this choice as other android cpu/abi were either too slow or just wouldn't allow me to install the required apps.

Edited: In the end, I was directed to use GenyMotion as that performed better in terms of speed. I was reluctant at first but, to my surprise that really is the case (It is super faster than ARM android studio alternative). Not only is it a great emulator, it also has this ARM translation tools that allows one to easily install ARM sl4a.apk on the x86 devices.